# Selenium click on dynamic id'd checkbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium

I am having a bit of trouble with this. I am trying to click on a check box with an ID that is different each page load.

This is the code I have that doesn't work:

```
Dim SegmentData As IWebElement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'gwt-uid-5')]")
SegmentData.click()
```

This is the xpath for the element:

> //*[@id="gwt-uid-5324"]

The last 3 digits (324 in this case) are what change.

Nothing I try seems to work for me as each click attempt always fails.

Here is the exception thrown in this instance:

> Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' in WebDriver.dll

And here is the HTML for the checkbox:

```
<div class="spee-f"> 
    <span class="gwt-CheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-5324" tabindex="0">    
        <label for="gwt-uid-5324">Segment statistics by month</label>     
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Show exception log and `HTML` for check box

Comment: do as @Grasshopper stated, as well as show the containers (at least 2 up?)

Comment: Hi see my edit please @sircapsalot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following `XPath` and let me know it error still occurs:

```
//span[label[text()="Segment statistics by month"]]/input[@type="checkbox"]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!